# Incorrect link "XXX posts edited" at the activity tab of user profile

Tags: discussion, edits, profile-page

Look at the impact block on the right side of the activity tab.

The link "XXX posts edited" leads to [the history of all my revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6263942/gleb-kemarsky?tab=activity&sort=revisions) - for publications from other users as well as for my own. I think it must lead to [the list of my suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6263942/gleb-kemarsky?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) for revisions of other user's publications.

Must be [image: correct link] instead of [image: incorrect link]

Comment: I came here expecting something completely different, and I feel disappointed.  And frustrated.

Comment: @Will Please explain what did you expect?

Comment: XXX posts, obviously.

Comment: @Will Oh!  Well, at least people laugh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it is not a bug. The link is correctly taking you to the *revisions* tab. Once you cross the 2000 reputation points mark, you get the *Edit Questions And Answers* privilege. You can make direct edits to posts which do not go through the review cycle and are not shown in the *suggestions* tab.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the privilege can change the meaning of the tabs.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky you are welcome. As a finer point, if you edit a tag wiki or its excerpt, it will still go through the review process and will be displayed under the suggestions tab (even if you crossed the 2000 mark)